# How to validate fields that are dynamically created in table in MVC using JQuery

Tags: jquery, validation

I have a HTMLtable in MVC application where I create/delete rows dynamically. On click of the save button in the page, I just want to do all the validations using JQuery that are mentioned in the model. Could anyone help me to validate the fields for that are dynamically created?

```
var firstName;
    $('#tableId tr:visible').has("td").each(function (row) {
        $(this).find('input,select,checkbox')
            .each(function (col) {
                $ctl = $(this);
                if ($ctl.is('input:text')) {
                    firstName = $ctl.val();
                    $ctl.rules('add', { required: true, messages: { required: 'First Name field is required'} });
                }
            });
    });
    var val = $("#formDealFeeRates").validate();
    val.showErrors();
    alert(val.valid());
```

Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `.form()` method of `$.validate()` to do a validation check at certain points, without having to do it beforehand.

That might not be too clear but essentially, rather than doing this:

```
var val = $("#formDealFeeRates").validate();
val.showErrors();
alert(val.valid());
```

You can do something like this:

```
$('#tabeId').on('submit', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    if ($(this).validate().form())
    {
        //this is valid, run save code here
    }
    else
    {
        //this is not valid. but you don't need to
        //do anything, validate will show the usual error messages.
    }
});
```

Doing it like this takes into account any fields that were added after the initial `$('form').validate()` call, as the check is performed anew each time the form is submitted.

Hope this helps / makes sense

Docs: http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Validator/form

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It may be silly to ask you, do I have to place this given code in my javascript function call? if I try to put the given code in my function SaveUsers(userId) { //I have put your code here.}, I am getting an error.